# Will this loop break always - double comparison

Tags: java, double

```
public void testLoop(double doubleTwo) {
   double doubleOne = 0;
   while (true) {
       if (doubleOne == doubleTwo) 
          break;
       double difference = doubleTwo - doubleOne;
       if (difference < 1)
          doubleOne = doubleOne + difference;
       else
          doubleOne = doubleOne + 1.0;
   }
}
```

I am concerned with the double comparison. But the code adds the epsilon difference. So will the loop always break?

Comment: but why not use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare(double, double)

Comment: It will not break if your argument is NaN. You should use `Double.compare()`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that.. 
at first `difference` will be > 1 for every `doubletwo` `>` than `1`.

so the value `doubleOne` *will increase by one in every iteration*.

After couple of iteration the value of `doubleOne` will be `>` than `doubleTwo`.

So the `difference` will be `<` than `1` and at that point 
`doubleOne` + `difference` will set the value of `doubleOne` and `doubleTwo` equal.
and the loop breaks.

When the `doubleTwo` is less than one the `difference` is added to `0` and of-course the number will be equal.

That's why the loop exits every time .

Answer (score 0):

The problematic thing I see with this loop is, that "double == double" is used.
As doubles are inexact per definition it would be more secure to test for a certain delta like `if (doubleOne - doubleTwo <= 0.00001)` or so.
My personal way of comparing doubles to see if they are really identical is

```
public static boolean equals (final double aObj1, final double aObj2)
{
  return (aObj1 == aObj2) || (Double.doubleToLongBits (aObj1) == Double.doubleToLongBits (aObj2));
}
```

hth